# which are the best front end web developer blogs

Tags: javascript, html

Looking for recommendations on industry-expert blogs from front-end web developers (emphasising RIA applications; e.g. HTML5, Javascript, AJAX, JQuery, Ext JS).

Trying to sort out the best from the rest. Which blogs are the well respected and worth following?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've personally made a JS+HTML5 google reader bundle of feeds for JavaScript developers

[JS+HTML5 bundle](https://www.google.com/reader/view/user%2F13665202698065518342%2Fbundle%2FThe%20HTML5%20JS%20Bundle#stream/user%2F13665202698065518342%2Fbundle%2FThe%20HTML5%20JS%20Bundle)

It mainly contains [coder.io #javascript](http://coder.io/tag/javascript) which is a bit hit and miss. It also contains reddit pages for JavaScript and HTML5.

As for personal blogs it contains :

- [Brendan Eich](http://brendaneich.com/)
- [dean edwards](http://brendaneich.com/)
- [eli grey](http://eligrey.com/blog/)
- [John resig](http://ejohn.org/category/blog/)
- [peter michaux](http://peter.michaux.ca/)
- [quirks blog](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/)
- [rob hawkes](http://rawkes.com/)

But the list doesn't contain "RIA applications blogs from industry-experts". This is because I don't know of any. The collection is still a solid read for any JavaScript developer.

Comment: Very good list.